# $\cos(\theta) = \cos(-\theta)$ which means that the cosine function is (blank)?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

I understand why $\cos(\theta) = \cos(-\theta)$ but I don't know what the specific property this question is asking for is - PreCalc homework.

Likewise, another question is:
$\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$ which means that the sine function is (blank)
which I again understand why it is but I don't know the property.

Comment: A function $f(x)$ which satisfies $f(x)=f(-x)$ is said to be Even (as $x^{2n}$ has this property). A function $f(x)$ which satisfies $f(x)=-f(-x)$ is said to be Odd (as $x^{2n+1}$ has this property).

Comment: Note that $x^{\rm even~number}$ is always an even function, and $x^{\rm odd~number}$ is always an odd function. I think this is where the names come from.

Answer (score 0):

The cosine function is **even** and the sine function is **odd**.

If you were just looking for those words, then that's your answer.  If not, you need to clarify the question further.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at the Unit Circle which shows how angles and their cosine and sine ratios 
[Unit Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2WQW.jpg)

The x axis represents the values of cosine of any angle and the y axis represents the values of sin of any angle. The sin and cos ratios of the negation of an angle are flipped on the x-axis. If you travel downwards in the y direction, the angle's sin will be flipped because y values are negated under the x-axis. If you travel left in the x direction, the cosine will remain the same since a flip in the x-axis does not negate the x value of a coordinate(which is cosine)